# Serializing generic c# model to xml in .net core 3.0

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-3.0

I am using .net core 3.0 to create Web APIs. I want to serialize a generic model to `XML`. But by default, it serializes the generic model to `JSON` only.

When I tried to serialize a simple model to `XML`, it gets serialized to `XML` properly.

Depending upon the headers passed, I want to serialize the model. Here is what I have done till now:

In startup.cs file:

```
services.AddControllers(options =>{
        options.RespectBrowserAcceptHeader = true; // false by default
    }).
    AddXmlSerializerFormatters().
```

Below is the example of code:

My Generic Model:

```
public class ApiResponseModel<T>
{
    public int ErrorCode { get; set; }
    public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }
    public T Data { get; set; }

    public ApiResponseModel(int errorCode, string errorMessage, T data)
    {
        this.ErrorCode = errorCode;
        this.ErrorMessage = errorMessage;
        this.Data = data;
    }
}
```

Action to return data:

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> Get()
{
    IEnumerable<RoleDTO> roleList = null;
    roleList = await _repository.RoleRepository.GetAllRolesAsync();
    var data = new ApiResponseModel<IEnumerable<RoleDTO>>(200, "Success", roleList);
    return Ok(data);
}
```

This return `JSON` response though `Accept` header is specified as `application/xml`.

But if I simply return roleList it gives the response in `XML` format.

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> Get()
{
    IEnumerable<RoleDTO> roleList = null;
    roleList = await _repository.RoleRepository.GetAllRolesAsync();
    return Ok(roleList);
}
```

How can I get the `XML` response for the generic models also?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There're two reasons :

1. Your `ApiResponseModel<T>`  has no parameterless constructor.
2. You're using `XmlSerializer` by `AddXmlSerializerFormatters()`(instead of XML DataContractSerializer), which will not take care of `IEnumerable<T>` serialization by default.

To fix this issue, add a parameterless constructor:

```
public class ApiResponseModel<T>
{
    public int ErrorCode { get; set; }
    public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }
    public T Data { get; set; }
    public ApiResponseModel() { }       // add a parameterless constructor

    public ApiResponseModel(int errorCode, string errorMessage, T data)
    {
        this.ErrorCode = errorCode;
        this.ErrorMessage = errorMessage;
        this.Data = data;
    }
}
```

And consider adding a XML `DataContractSerializer` formatters to take care of `IEnumerable<T>` serialization:

```
services.AddControllersWithViews(opts =>{
    opts.RespectBrowserAcceptHeader = true;
})
.AddXmlDataContractSerializerFormatters()
.AddXmlSerializerFormatters()
```

Comment: your solution worked like charm. Thanks a lot. But, By how including a parameterless constructor for the model resolved this? Can you give a brief about this or how you pointed out the exact problems.? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Sunny12 I'm not a smart man like Jon Skeet who can compile & run the code within the brain. So I just checkout the log and the log tells me that there should be a parameterless constructor :)

Comment: ok, then it would be my bad to overlook those logs. Anyways, thanks. @itminus